# Reenable Google Play Services after disable

Tags: google-play-services, application-manager

I am developing an app that requires testing without google play services (I'm on a Samsung S3). I've turned google play services off in Application Manager and tested everything. Afterwards, I went back in and turned it back on, but I can't seem to get my app to recognize that google play services are re-enabled. What ways are there to check it Google Play Services is indeed enabled again on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

After further debugging, google play services' connection was coming across as needing an update in my app's code. It turns out I had to clear Google Play Service's cache. Once I did that and turned on, it prompted me to install updates. I did that, and now it recognizes it as re-enabled as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Under Application Manager, there should be two Google Play Services instances under "Running Apps".  These instances will also indicate which services are active, and that they were launched by an application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is reset app prefernces. Go to settings-app management-reset app prefernces. I tried all the above methods and nothing worked. I tried this by trial and error method and work done.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings - Applications, then go to options tool and select "Reset preferences". It will start working again. I tried in Micromax.